# IE9 links with target not working

Tags: hyperlink, internet-explorer-9, href

I see a strange behavoir in IE9:

```
    1 <a href="http://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">Link is not working in IE9</a>
    2 <a href="http://stackoverflow.com" target="mywindow">Link is not working in IE9</a>
    3 <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Link is working in IE9</a>
```

Testing it with an IE8, all 3 links work fine. Testing it with one IE9 link 1 and 2 don't work (unfortunately, I have nobody with an IE9 to do tests if this is a general problem in IE9 or just on the system I'm testing).

I tried to do this http://www.pcwindowstips.com/2007/internet-explorer-tips/hyperlinks-not-working-in-internet-explorer/ but without success. Even resetting the interner-setting didn't help.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

using this snippet it worked for me, but opened in new tabs not new windows:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test a</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="http://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">Link is not working in IE9</a>
        <a href="http://stackoverflow.com" target="mywindow">Link is not working in IE9</a>
        <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Link is working in IE9</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

How certain are you that they are not being blocked by a popup blocker?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your code doesn't work either for me. I have turned off the popup-blocker at Internet-Options -> Privacy -> Uncheck "Turn on Popup-Blocker", but it still doesn't work. 

I'm not aware that I installed any other add-ins that could block popups (usually I browse with FF or Chrome).

But if it works for you, it has to be a problem on my system.

Comment: Just tested: If I put the mouse over a link without target -> right button -> open in new window, nothing happens as well... If I just click the link, it works...

Comment: It seems to be a problem of the tabs in IE: If you turn on tabs and tell IE to open links in new windows instead of new tabs, it doesn't work. If you tell IE to open links in new tabs, it works. Kind of strange...

Comment: Write it as an answer and tick it so people will know what to do in future if they experience the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem of the tabs in IE: If you turn on tabs and tell IE to open links in new windows instead of new tabs, it doesn't work. If you tell IE to open links in new tabs, it works.